# Form conflicting with JQuery animation

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a div (`id="right"`) which holds a form with a submit button. Upon clicking Submit, the div should reduce its width. Works fine when I delete the `<form>` tags from my HTML, but doesn't work when the form is there. How come?

HTML:

```
<div id="right">
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
        ... some input fields here ...
        <input id = "btnRight" type="submit" value="Submit">            
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#right {
    width: 50%;
    min-width: 35px;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#btnRight').click(function () {
        $('#right').animate({ width: '3%' }, 'slow');   
    });
});
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent buttons from submitting forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use preventDefault function for event, it will cancel default "submit" event:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#btnRight').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#right').animate({ width: '3%' }, 'slow');   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `preventDefault()`

*If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.*

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#btnRight').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
        $('#right').animate({ width: '3%' }, 'slow');   
    });
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gk3eU/1/)